# How to open a modal in a child page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I try to open a modal in a child window which was in the parent page. But the data in the parent window was not detected by the modal

```
<a href="" class="modalButton" data-toggle="modal" data-src="mypage.php" data-height=900 data-width=860 data-target="#myModal">
```

I use the above code in the child page. I need to open the `#MyModal` on child page which was in the parent page

**Modal code**

```html
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" onclick="closemodal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: are you using modal for child window or jquery popup?

Comment: <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <button type="button" onclick="closemodal()" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <iframe frameborder="0"></iframe>
      </div>
      
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


This is the code I used in the model. This code is working in the parent class when i use the link in the Question. But it is not working in the child page. But the model is opening without displaying any data.

Comment: add more code like you parent page and child page code.

Comment: my question is modal within modal or child window and then modal what?

Comment: This is the js function that I used to call the model

Comment: where is the function?edit question add it.

Comment: $('a.modalButton').on('click', function(e) {
    var src = $(this).attr('data-src');
    var height = $(this).attr('data-height') || 300;
var width = $(this).attr('data-width') || 400;
    $("#myModal iframe").attr({'src':src,
'height': height,
'width': width});
});

Comment: please check the link for more details

http://imgur.com/9Bo84dN